# installing eclipse, stuck

Tags: eclipse, nano

Noob here, setting up my first linux box.

I'm following this page to install [eclipse](http://colinrrobinson.com/technology/install-eclipse-ubuntu/)

I get to the part where it says to save the nano file - but it's asking me for a file name and I don't know what to give it. (or if the file should be in a certain directory)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that guide is trying to install eclipse system-wide. There is usually no reason to do that, if you can get away with not doing it.

Just extract the archive and run `eclipse` (`./eclipse` from the command prompt, once you have `cd`'d into the directory). It even works without using the command line at all.

Comment: Thanks. Should I leave things as is or undo some of the steps?

Comment: you should undo the system wide steps since they might conflict with apt's eclipse